# I want to loop the time so whenever except statement will hit time will increase by 10%

Tags: python, algebra

whenever except statement will hit time will increase by 10% instead of 10 seconds also it should print time before it will increase

```
from time import sleep
A = 10
B = 'ten'

while True:
    sleep_time = 10
    try:
        print(A-B)

    except:
        print('starting loop')
        sleep(sleep_time)
        sleep_time+=10
```

Comment: If you want to increase 10% just do `sleep_time *= 1.1`

Comment: thank you, but what is 1.1?

Comment: It is a number. If you are from Italy, you are probably familiar with comma as decimal separator (1,1) but in Python programming we use a dot (derives from what is normal in English speaking countries).

Comment: This is algebra, not Python.  How do you increase a quantity by 10%?

Comment: If you want it to be more clear that you're increasing by percentage, then use this `sleep_time = sleep_time * (100 + increase_by) / 100` where `increase_by` is then a percentage value.  This will round the result to a whole integer value.  If you want the result to be able to have a fractional component, then use `sleep_time = sleep_time * (100.0 + increase_by) / 100`

Answer (score 1):

You have one big issue in that sleep_time is never going to change because you set it to 10 at the top of every loop iteration.  Fixing that, and making the changes to do what I think you're asking for, here's a modified version of your code:

```
from time import sleep
A = 10
B = 'ten'
increase_sleep_by = 10 # percentage value

sleep_time = 10.0

while True:
    try:
        print(A-B)

    except:
        print('will sleep for ' + str(sleep_time) + ' seconds before retrying')
        sleep(sleep_time)
        sleep_time *= (100.0 + increase_sleep_by) / 100
```

which producers:

```
will sleep for 10.0 seconds before retrying
will sleep for 11.0 seconds before retrying
will sleep for 12.100000000000001 seconds before retrying
will sleep for 13.310000000000002 seconds before retrying
will sleep for 14.641000000000004 seconds before retrying
will sleep for 16.105100000000004 seconds before retrying
will sleep for 17.715610000000005 seconds before retrying
...
```